# Why do both x11vnc and x0vncserver fail in similar ways in Gnome Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: vnc

I'd like to be able to login to my remote Ubuntu 22.04 and see the Desktop *as shown on that machine*. (I know how to create a `vncserver` with a separate desktop instance). I have separate problems with the built-in Remote Desktop, so this is specifically about `x11vnc` and `x0vncserver`.

They have worked fine for me for years on 18.04 under Xfce.

Now on 22.04, they fail in similar ways, so I suspect this is really a Gnome or Xorg (or - is Compiz even a thing any more?) problem. This suspicion is made stronger by the fact that it works fine using [`gnome-session-flashback`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback).

I have fiddled with many options for both `x11vnc` and `x0vncserver`, but my problem remains.

Short version: When I move a window, I see both the original window in its original position and the window in the new position. And perhaps a window or two in the path that the window was moved. E.g. here I started with a single terminal:

[image: original single window]

Then I moved the window:

[image: Moved window]

Only the bottom-right one is interactive...

Now the trick... If I stop both the client and the vnc server, and start different client and vncservers, the move artifacts remain. Here is a reproduction recipe (here, "client" is the Debian machine running the vnc client, "server" is the Ubuntu 22.04 machine running a vnc server):

- Start with a freshly rebooted server.
- Connect the first time

  - Start `x11vnc -usepw -display :0 -forever -rfbport 5901` on the server
  - Connect with Remmina from the client
  - In the vnc client:

    - See one window (first screenshot above)
    - Move the window
    - See two or more windows (second screenshot above)
  - Kill the Remmina client
  - Kill the `x11vnc` server process
- Connect a second time

  - Start `x0vncserver -rfbport=5901 -PasswordFile=/home/peter/.vnc/passwd -display=:0 -fg` on the server
  - Connect with `xtigervncviewer` to the client
  - See two or more windows!!! The original already-moved window is still there. The "old position artifact" remains (but looks a little different notice that top-right is actually two overlapping windows):

[image: second vnc connection]

So somehow the history of the original window position is stored on the server and survives an `x11vnc`/`x0vncserver` restart. Which leads me to believe that this really is a Gnome/Xorg/Compiz problem.

**Edit:** Additional data points

- I tried installing `gnome-session-flashback` and when using a flashback session `x11vnc` works as I expect. But I don't actually want to run `gnome-session-flashback` forever. I expect (but haven't tested) that e.g. XFCE will work fine too.
- I'm using the open source `amdgpu` driver for my `Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:67ff] (rev ff)` graphcis card. I tried installing and using the AMD proprietary drivers, and it made no difference.
- It also works fine in a VirtualBox virtual machine, that obviously doesn't use the AMD graphics drivers.

Has anybody seen something like this before? And knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was because I am using a KVM switch. I have one desktop running `x11vnc` and another (a laptop) with the VNC client. Every time I used the laptop I did so by switching the KVM switch to show the laptop, *which disconnects the monitor from the machine running `x11vnc`*.

If I leave the KVM switch on the `x11vnc1` machine and use the laptop's screen to run the VNC client, all is well. As soon as I switch the KVM switch away from the `x11vnc` server, the problem appears.

I've filed: [LibVNC/x11vnc#234](https://github.com/LibVNC/x11vnc/issues/234): "x11vnc has display artifacts and works slowly if monitor is disconnected or used with a KVM switch." for this.

And I plan on working around this problem with an EDID Emulator. I've ordered [this one](http://www.logilink.info/Products_LogiLink/Cable_Adapters/HDMI_Adapter/HDMI_EDID_Emulator_HD0105_LogiLink.htm). It hopefully lets the computer think the display is still attached. And then next time I update the KVM switch, get one with a built-in EDID emulator. I'll try to remember to update this thread when the EDID emulator arrives and I've tried it out.